# How to compare 2 arrays for common items in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I am writing a script to compare the achievements of one player to another in a game. In each of the arrays the id and timestamp will match up on some entries. I have included a sample of one of the start of the 2 separate arrays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8213
            [timestamp] => 1384420404000
            [url] => http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=8213&who=Azramon&when=1384420404000
            [name] => Friends In Places Higher Yet
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6460
            [timestamp] => 1384156380000
            [url] => http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=6460&who=Azramon&when=1384156380000
            [name] => Hydrophobia
        )
```

I want to find all of the array items where the id and timestamp match. I have looked into array_intersect but I don't think this is what I am looking for as it will only find items when the entries are identical. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into http://us1.php.net/in_array ? It could be used together with a `foreach` loop

Comment: I did try this but with up to 10000 entries each it takes too long to find all the matches. I did this by running through each item in the first one and trying to match the second array. It failed due to the server taking too long to respond. It got through about 20 entries before dying by the looks of it.

Comment: With that many entries I think any function will take a long time. But there may be more efficient functions that I don't know of.

Comment: Ok, thanks heaps. I will research ways of comparing 2 large arrays in PHP. That has helped, thanks.

Comment: Do you store the arrays in a Database?

Comment: The arrays are generated from 2 separate JSON results from an external server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
   $key_match = Array();
   //Loop first array
   foreach($array as $key => $element){
      //Compare to second array 
      if($element == $array2[$key]){
          //Store matching keys
          $key_match[] = $key;
      }
   }
?>
```

$key_match will be an array with all matching keys.

(I'm at work and havn't had time to test the code)

Hope it helps

EDIT: 
Fully working example below:

```
<?php
$a1["t"] = "123";
$a1["b"] = "124";
$a1["3"] = "125";
$a2["t"] = "123";
$a2["b"] = "124";
$a2["3"] = "115";

$key_match = Array();

    //Loop first array
    foreach($a1 as $key => $element){
        //Compare to second array 
        if($element == $a2[$key]){
           //Store matching keys
           $key_match[] = $key;
   }
}

var_dump($key_match);
?>
```

Comment: I attempted this but returned a blank result. Will confirm that the ID and TIMESTAMP match in both arrays.

Comment: try adding:  var_dump($key_match);  tryied it now, it works for me!

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I used print_r at the end to output the $key_match. Tried it with var_dump also and got "array(0) {}"

Comment: Thank you for the code, that helped me get it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`array_intersect_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go on an exploration of **array callback functions**, take a look at **array_uintersect**.  It's like array_intersect except you specify a function to use for the comparison.  This means you can write your own.

Unfortunately, you need to implement a function that returns -1, 0 or 1 based on less than, same as, greater than, so you need more code.  But I suspect that it'll be the most efficient way of doing what you're looking for.

```
function compareArrays( $compareArray1, $compareArray2 ) {
    if ( $compareArray1['id'] == $compareArray2['id'] && $compareArray1['timestamp'] == $compareArray2['timestamp'] ) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ( $compareArray1['id'] < $compareArray2['id']  ) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ( $compareArray1['id'] > $compareArray2['id']  ) {
        return 1;
    }
    if ( $compareArray1['timestamp'] < $compareArray2['timestamp']  ) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ( $compareArray1['timestamp'] > $compareArray2['timestamp']  ) {
        return 1;
    }
}

var_dump( array_uintersect( $array1, $array2, "compareArrays") );
```